# Send request on unload and/or beforeunload doesn't work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, onbeforeunload, onunload

I know this issue has been answered already on SO but I cannot make it work on mobile browsers.

I need to send a request to my server when some web page is closed (tab or window closed).

Here is what I do:

```
    window.addEventListener("unload",function(e) {
        var pl = "bla=blabla";
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST","http://myapi/myendpoint",false);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send(pl);
    },false);

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(e) {
        var pl = "bla=blabla";
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST","http://myapi/myendpoint",false);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send(pl);
    },false);
```

This works fine on desktop (chrome and Firefox) if the page is either refreshed or its tab/window is closed.

On mobile, it only works when the page is refreshed or if we enter another url. **It doesn't work if we close the tab or the program (chrome/safari...)**. So far, I've tested it with:

- Chrome on Samsung S5 (Android 4.4.2)
- Default browser on Samsung S5 (Android 4.4.2)
- Safari on iPad 3 (iOS 8.0.2)
- Chrome on iPad 3 (iOS 8.0.2)

**On mobile, the request is never sent if we close the tab** :(!

How can I make it fully work on mobile as well? (ie when the page tab or browser is closed/shut down) ?

Comment: Looks like on iOS `unload` event is not supported but `pagehide` should do it, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5).

Comment: @DavidDomain thanks for your answer. I have edited the question and added this precision : it works when refreshing the page, so it's not an unsupported event issue... I've also tested the pagehide event anyway and the behavior is the same.

Comment: @Żabojad, did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @aweeeezy nop, I've changed my entire workflow to workaround this problem. The app regularly pings the server so that I know more or less when the user has left the page...